# Is there any way I can tell if my code is being compiled with cl.exe?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, cl.exe

This has probably been asked before, but I couldn't find it.

Is there a way to determine, at compile time, if my code is being compiled by `cl.exe`?

I will be using this to conditionally include (during preprocessing, via `#ifdef`) certain `#pragma` directives only supported by `cl.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make decisions on the `cl.exe` version, use `_MSC_BUILD`.

However, first check for `_MSC_VER`, because `_MSC_BUILD` was not available in VS 2005.

Comment: Microsoft has used `_MSC_VER` for their own conditional compilation, so that seems like the way to go.

Comment: @Mark: Excellent, that means it won't be disappearing any time soon. Thanks Sam, that's done the trick!

Comment: Heh.  If `_MSC_VER` disappeared, a whole lot of code would break :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check for the `_MSC_BUILD` macro.

Comment: [This](http://predef.sourceforge.net/precomp.html) seems to indicate that it's undocumented, and only available in VS2008+. I do have VS2008, but I hesitate to rely on undocumented macros ;-)

Comment: @Cameron: I found it in the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)...

Comment: Oho, your reference beats my reference :-) +1 for the excellent link, thanks!